# File CaesarShift Crypto

Tags: c, file, encryption

I'm trying to crypt a file using ceasarshift, a new file called .enc is being created but it's empty.
Here's my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* getFileExtension(const char*);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int shift = (int)argv[1];
    int byte;
    const char *fileName = (char*)argv[2];
    char *fileExtension = getFileExtension(fileName);
    char *newFileName = (char*)fileName;
    FILE *f_in;
    FILE *f_out;
    f_in = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (strcmp(fileExtension, "enc") == 0)
    {
        // We want to decrypt the file
        strcat(newFileName, ".dec");
        f_out = fopen(newFileName, "w");
        while ((byte = fgetc(f_in) != EOF))
        {
            fputc(byte - shift, f_out);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // We want to encrypt the file
        strcat(newFileName, ".enc");
        f_out = fopen(newFileName, "w");
        while ((byte = fgetc(f_in) != EOF))
        {
            fputc(byte + shift, f_out);
        }
    }
    fclose(f_in);
    fclose(f_out);
    return 0;
}

char* getFileExtension(const char *fileName)
{
    char *extension;
    int foundExtension = 0;
    while (*fileName)
    {
        if (foundExtension == 1)
        {
            *extension++ = *fileName++;
        }
        if (*fileName == '.')
        {
            foundExtension = 1;
        }
        fileName++;
    }
    return extension;
}
```

I've made a txt file named CryptoFile which contains the following text :

```
This is a crypto test file !
```

This is the parameters I sent in the console when running the exe :

```
FileCaesarShift.exe 15 CryptoFile
```

So the shift is 15, the file to encrypt/decrypt is called "CryptoFile"
although a file called CryptoFile.enc is being created it's simply empty.
Can someone tell me what I did wrong ?

Ok I've found out that I need to pass CryptoFile.txt including the ".txt" but I wish to remove it from the name of the new files that will be created so instead of creating CryptoFile.txt.enc I want only CryptoFile.enc so I made a removeExtension function but my program crashes , here's the new code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* getFileExtension(const char*);
void removeFileExtension(char*);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const int shift = (int)argv[1];
    int byte;
    const char *fileName = (char*)argv[2];
    char *fileExtension = getFileExtension(fileName);
    char *newFileName = (char*)fileName;
    removeFileExtension(newFileName);
    printf("newfilename value is %s", *newFileName);
    FILE *f_in;
    FILE *f_out;
    f_in = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (strcmp(fileExtension, "enc") == 0)
    {
        // We want to decrypt the file
        strcat(newFileName, ".dec");
        f_out = fopen(newFileName, "w");
        while ((byte = fgetc(f_in)) != EOF)
        {
            fputc(byte - shift, f_out);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // We want to encrypt the file
        strcat(newFileName, ".enc");
        f_out = fopen(newFileName, "w");
        while ((byte = fgetc(f_in)) != EOF)
        {
            printf("byte is %d\n", byte);
            fputc(byte + shift, f_out);
        }
    }
    fclose(f_in);
    fclose(f_out);
    return 0;
}

char* getFileExtension(const char *fileName)
{
    char *extension;
    int foundExtension = 0;
    while (*fileName)
    {
        if (foundExtension == 1)
        {
            *extension++ = *fileName++;
        }
        if (*fileName == '.')
        {
            foundExtension = 1;
        }
        fileName++;
    }
    return extension;
}

void removeFileExtension(char *fileName)
{
    while (*fileName)
    {
        if (*fileName == '.')
        {
            *fileName == '\0';
            break;
        }
        fileName++;
    }
}
```

***LATEST EDIT :***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void copyFileExtension(char*, char*);
int getFileNameLengthWithoutExtension(char*);
int getFileExtensionLength(char*);
void copyFileNameWithoutExtension(char*, char*);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int shift = atoi(argv[1]);
    int byte;
    char *fileName = (char*)argv[2];
    char *fileExtension = malloc(getFileExtensionLength(fileName) + 1);
    copyFileExtension(fileExtension, fileName);
    char *newFileName = malloc(getFileNameLengthWithoutExtension(fileName) + 5);
    copyFileNameWithoutExtension(newFileName, fileName);
    FILE *f_in;
    FILE *f_out;
    f_in = fopen(fileName, "r");
    if (strcmp(fileExtension, "enc") == 0)
    {
        // We want to decrypt the file
        puts("dec");
        strcat(newFileName, ".dec");
        f_out = fopen(newFileName, "w");
        while ((byte = fgetc(f_in)) != EOF)
        {
            fputc(byte - shift, f_out);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        puts("enc");
        // We want to encrypt the file
        strcat(newFileName, ".enc");
        f_out = fopen(newFileName, "w");
        while ((byte = fgetc(f_in)) != EOF)
        {
            fputc(byte + shift, f_out);
        }
    }
    fclose(f_in);
    fclose(f_out);
    return 0;
}

void copyFileExtension(char *fileExtension, char *fileName)
{
    char *token = strtok(fileName, ".");
    token = strtok(NULL, ".");
    strcpy(fileExtension, token);
}

int getFileNameLengthWithoutExtension(char *fileName)
{
    if (*fileName && *fileName != '.')
    {
        return 1 + getFileNameLengthWithoutExtension(++fileName);
    }
    return 0;
}

int getFileExtensionLength(char *fileName)
{
    int foundExt = 0;
    int len = 0;
    while(*fileName)
    {
        if (foundExt == 1)
        {
            len++;
        }
        if (*fileName == '.')
        {
            foundExt = 1;
        }
        fileName++;
    }
    printf("ext len is %d\n", len);
    return len;
}

void copyFileNameWithoutExtension(char* dest, char *source)
{
    char *fileNameWithoutExtension = strtok(source, ".");
    strcpy(dest, fileNameWithoutExtension);
}
```

Comment: There are no guarantees that the memory allocated for the string in `argv` resides in a writable memory segment.

Comment: @SleuthEye I don't write to any of the args

Comment: you write to newFileName which points to the same address as filename, which points to the same address as argv[2].

Comment: Also, `*newFilename` is not a `char*` required by the "%s" string format specifier, which would result in undefined behavior (could be a crash). You should use `newFilename` as argument to your `printf("newfilename value`...

Comment: @SleuthEye Ok I've made some changes, the encrypted file is being created but the it's empty as if it's not copying any bytes from the input file, I've updated my code would you mind pointing my mistake now ?

Comment: From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/, "Notice that this string is __modified__ by being broken into smaller strings". So if you are going to use `strtok`, you're probably better served with a copy of the string. Also, I'm assuming you are now trying to open "CryptoFile.txt", make sure this file exists (since you had originally created "CryptoFile" without extension, and your code is not checking for fopen failure).

Comment: @SleuthEye yea that fixed my problem, also how do I check for fopen failure ? should I just do if(f_in == NULL) return 1; ?

Comment: You should `free` whatever you allocated before returning, but that's essentially it. Otherwise, you may also want to output some useful indications to the user (eg. with `printf("Failed to open %s", fileName)`) but that's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things one can notice at a quick glance:

- `const int shift = (int)argv[1]` does not convert the input argument to the integer value 15. Rather it casts the `char*` pointer in `argv[1]` (that is the address) into an `int` and assigns that (typically quite large) value to `shift`. To actually convert the input argument into an `int` consider using `atoi`.
- you are not allocating memory for `newFileName`, and later writing possibly past the allocated length of the "constant" input `argv[2]` which `newFileName` points to (which results in undefined behavior).
- Assuming the program doesn't crash before that, the operator precedence rule between `=` and `!=` makes your while loop arguments equivalent to `byte = (fgetc(f_in) != EOF)`. So before you reach EOF, `byte == 1`. If you had a shift of 15 you wind up creating a file full of unreadable control characters (ascii character 16). Given the unpredictable `shift` from the first bullet, who knows what is actually going to be written to file.

Though these are probably not your specific errors, the following could also cause problem:

- You are also not checking whether the files were opened successfully before using them
- Have you consider what would happen for letters that are near the end of the valid characters?

Comment: I understand the first bullet point and the third which I already found out and fixed by myself, about the second I'm not sure I quite understand, can't I just make the newFileName pointer to point to the fileName pointer without allocating ? and If I must allocate how much would I need ? I chose pointer rather than a char[] because I couldn't predict the file length name so I thought pointers are more suitable, please feel free to correct me as I'm still learning. Also edited my OP about another problem I've found

Comment: @AALC file name length can be computed using `strlen`, adding space for the extension and the extra '\0' string termination characters (so strlen(argv[2]) + 5 in this specific case).